# Unable to call the Procedure After converting via AWS SCT FROM DB2 To Postgresql RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, db2, amazon-rds

DB2 :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "DB2INST2"."MYPROC" () 

  RESULT SETS 1

  LANGUAGE SQL  

SPECIFIC SQL220506022203869

BEGIN 

     DECLARE c1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR select * from EMP.EMPLOYEESDET;
      
     OPEN c1;
     
  END
```

After Converting Postgresql :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE db2inst2.myproc(INOUT c$myproc refcursor[])

AS 

$BODY$

DECLARE

    c1 CURSOR FOR

    SELECT  *    FROM emp.employeesdet;

    c1$ISOPEN BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;

    c1$ISFOUND BOOLEAN DEFAULT false;

    c1$CURSOR_ROWCOUNT BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

BEGIN
   
    OPEN c1;

    c1$ISOPEN := TRUE;

    c$myproc := c$myproc || c1;

END;


$BODY$


LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How could call this procedure in postgresql ?

Note : aws_db2_ext schema has been used.

Comment: If you want to return a result, use a set-returning function. Postgres isn't DB2. Things are done differently there

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Db2 also supports set-returning functions (only they are called differently), so there must have been a reason whoever wrote that SP chose an SP and not a function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_nam okay with you but  my question was that how to call in postgresql if above code is  correct and aws_db2_ext is used. So can't understand how to call this under Postgresql.

Comment: @mustaccio    I am use like                                                                                                                 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE db2inst2.myproc(
 INOUT c1 refcursor)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
begin
open c1 for select * from emp.employeesdet;
end;
$BODY$;                                                                                                                                      It is working but when use extension (aws_db2_ext) that time can't call  . Pls suggest.